# Static variable and method in Django models file and how to add a decimal field for a static variable in Django admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin, global-variables, class-variables

I'm making a web page by using Django that counts coin collected. Each coin has its coin_type and coin_count. I also want to have a static total variable "total" that calculates the total amount of coins. I want to make a function that can calculate the sum of all instances' coin_count and assign that value to total. However, when I declare "total" inside the class, its value is different for every instances.
Moreover, I don't know how to have a decimal field for a static variable in Django admin interface.

In the code below, I create a global variable "total" so that its value doesn't change for every class instances. However, every time I change the code or restart the server, its value is reset to 0.

This is my models.py file

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
total = 0

class Coin(models.Model):
    coin_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coin_count = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,decimal_places=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.coin_type

    def count(self):
        return self.coin_count

    def increase(self):
        self.coin_count += 1

    @staticmethod
    def find_total():
        global total
        return total
```

I want to have a static variable "total" that has the same value for all instances and a static method "calculate_total" that calculates the sum of all instances' "coin_count".
If possible, can anyone help me create a Decimal Field for "total" in Django admin interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the total will reset when you restart if it's just stored as a variable in memory; what else would you expect?

It makes even less sense in an environment like Django, which will usually be served by multiple processes that don't share global data.

But there's no point in doing this. Coins are stored in the database, so to get the total you should ask the database to do a Sum query:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Coin.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('coin_count'))
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!
Also, is there a way that I can add 'total' into Django admin interface?